# External effects in App development in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I have developed an app in IOS. It is working fine independently. But i want to know how it can be affected by other processes going in  the device. For eg; if an SMS or an incoming call is received when app is in foreground. Then we may have to pause the app and so on. I want to know what all other factors can be there which can affect the app and how i need to handle those such that app data is retained. If i can get the list of such external factors and procedure to handle them, then i my problem will be solved. 
By the way, i am using phonegap(cordova) version 2.1.0 with ARC enabled in IOS.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: By reading the title, I thought about trees and water, not SMS and incoming calls ;)

Comment: i changed it. Hope its fine now.

Comment: Oh but I liked it the way it was! :þ

Comment: Check multi-tasking in iOS here -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 1):

All of the things that can interrupt your app are passed through the UIApplicationDelegate. Here is the Apple documentation about it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate